# Signal when a ReplaySubject has "finished"

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, angular-observable

I am trying to figure out a good way to signal that a ReplaySubject is currently "empty".

```
import {ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
const rs = new ReplaySubject<Object>();

 // ...
constructor(){
  this.sub =  rs.subscribe(...);
}
```

everytime the constructor is called, it will replay all the items from the subject. However my question is - is there some event we can listen for, that tells us when the subject becomes empty?

The only thing that I can think of is to fire a custom/different event when subject is done, something like this:

```
rs.next({done:true});
```

is passing data to the next() method the best way to signal that ReplaySubject is (temporarily) empty/out of events?

Comment: It's kind of confusing what you're looking for. By "finished" you mean calling `complete()`? By "empty" you mean it haven't received any `next()` call yet? Subjects can't become empty by calling any of their method.

Comment: By "finished" i meant it's the last time `next()` is called on that subject

Answer (score 5):

Because Subject is also an Observer you can call `complete()` after the final `next()` call. Then you can listen it with 3rd parameter of `subscribe(...)` method.

```
const rs = new ReplaySubject<Object>();
rs.next({a: 1})
rs.complete()

rs.subscribe(
    obj => console.log(obj),
    error => {},
    () => console.log('completed')
);
// Outputs
// {a: 1} completed
```

Answer (score 1):

Well now, I suppose you could setup a secondary observable to tell you what the last item being replayed is:

```
const last$ = rs.replay(1);
```

Then you'd just combineLatest and scan ... once you've reached the item emitted by last$ then your ReplaySubject has finishing replaying:

```
this.sub = Observable.combineLatest(
  rs,
  last$.take(1)
).scan((acc: { item: Object, isReplay: boolean }, curr: [Object, Object]) => {
    return {item: curr[0], isReplay: acc.isReplay && curr[0] !== curr[1]};
  }, {isReplay: true}
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Mr. Miller do you think the answer from @Voskanyan David is better? seems simpler

Comment: The wording of your question says "the best way to signal that ReplaySubject is (temporarily) empty/out of events". @Voskanyan David's answer tells you when the ReplaySubject has completed (is permanently out of events)